# Exception while accessing 'FileOpenPicker' for the SecondTime in WindowsStoreApps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to open FileOpenPicker for two times one after the other.i.e)After selecting the image from FileOpenPicker for first time it returns back to the page with the selected image,that time a MessageDialog is shown,And clicking OK button on MessageDialog I am opening the FileOpenPicker again,this time I get a weird crash on

```
open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
```

as 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'.And My code is below.

```
 private async void PickImage()
    {
        FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

            open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

            // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
             open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
             open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
             open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
             open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
             open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

            StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (file != null)
            {
                if (prop1.Source == null)
                {                                         
                    Dialogpopup();
                    return;
                }
                else if (prop2.Source == null)
                {                      
                    Dialogpopup();
                    return;
                }                   
            }
        }

 private async void Dialogpopup()
    {
        MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Would you like to add additional photos?");
        UICommand okBtn = new UICommand("Yes");
        okBtn.Invoked = OkBtnClick;
        msgDialog.Commands.Add(okBtn);

        UICommand cancelBtn = new UICommand("No");
        cancelBtn.Invoked = CancelBtnClick;
        msgDialog.Commands.Add(cancelBtn);

        //Show message
        msgDialog.ShowAsync();
    }

 private async void OkBtnClick(IUICommand command)
    {                       
            img_PointerPressed(img_galary, null);           
    }

 private void img_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
       if (sender == img_galary)
        {
           PickImage();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.Clear()`? You new it up, so this is not necessary.

Comment: If I comment that statement,it crashes on  "open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp")".

Comment: Try move the code `if (file != null) ...' to the second function and call it after awaited call to picker. It looks like you call Picker twice. Yes, you use async/await, but garbage collector may cause it, I think.

Comment: If I Move 'if (file != null)' the messageDialog is not prompting.I want the Message Dialog to prompt after selecting image to page from the Picker.

Comment: I mean add  PickImageMain(), where you will call await PickImage() and check returned value by PickImage() (add return value StorageFile and remove if (file != null)... ). Then call the dialogs in async mode from  PickImageMain(). In the img_PointerPressed() call PickImageMain() again.

Comment: same exception occuring again like."A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in PalmAgent.exe

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."